# videojs 4.0 meet strange on IE9

Tags: video.js

I embed the js through cdn.
my img source and video source all load from romote disk,the img can't scale to the player size.
when I click the play button,but can't play the video.
my website link：
http://www.zeguoren.com/thread-6463-1-1.html

Answer (score 0):

According to W3C [HTML5 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-video-poster):

> The image given by the poster attribute, the poster frame, is intended
>   to be a representative frame of the video (typically one of the first
>   non-blank frames) that gives the user an idea of what the video is
>   like.

So you should use an image for the poster attribute that fit to the size of video.
If you want to see poster img, you also have to set preload attribute to 'none' or 'metadata' (see [here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/html5/poster/)).

About video, Internet Explorer 9 support only .mp4 format. So you should add a source:

```
<video data-setup="{}" poster="http://img142.poco.cn/[...]2043.jpg"
  preload="none" class="vjs-tech" id="my_video_1" tabindex="0">
  <source type="video/mp4" src="http://storage.live.com/items/F[...]2B!290?a.mp4"></source>
  <source type="video/webm" src="http://storage.live.com/items/F[...]2B!290?a.webm"></source>
</video>
```